# Connection reset when using proxy

Tags: java, ssl, proxy, jackson

I'm using Jackson's ObjectMapper class to make a request to a URL. This is working fine on my local machine (Mac), but is failing from my Unix VM. The difference is that my VM is behind a firewall, and my mac is not. However, both machines have access to the same proxy.

Seems like there might be some SSL issue involved. Can anyone spot the issue?

Using the following system properties in both deployments:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", _config.getProxyHost());
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", _config.getProxyPort());
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", _config.getProxyHost());
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", _config.getProxyPort());
```

Here is the full stacktrace from the unix box:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:954)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1511)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1038)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory._optimizedStreamFromURL(JsonFactory.java:1420)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory.java:730)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2137)
```

And when I am using: -Djavax.net.debug=ssl I see the following:

```
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 286
main, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
main, called closeSocket()
```

Comment: Why not open the stream yourself and pass the stream to jackson, instead of passing it the URL?

Comment: Not quite sure how that would make a difference :(. Just tried it and received the same issue (with a different origin)  Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
 ...
 at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1038)

Comment: Now you know that it is nothing to do with Jackson

Answer (score 2):

> The difference is that my VM is behind a firewall, and my mac is not. However, both machines have access to the same proxy.
>
> main, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

The peer closed the connection inside the handshake. Given that the difference between the working and non-working version is a firewall in between this firewall is probably blocking access, i.e. the connection reset is issued by the firewall.